# Bazel- How to get all transitive sources of a target

Tags: bazel, bazel-aspect

I have a need to write a rule which zips up all transitive config files (`*.foo`) of an executable (can be custom rule, java_binary and docker container_image).
The config files can appear on the `srcs` attribute of any attribute of the executable (`tars`, `deps`, `runtime_deps`, etc)

This sounds like it should be rather easy to do with an [aspect](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/aspects.html) attached to my rule but I lost my way between the various examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sources_aspect.bzl`:

```py
SourceFiles = provider(
    fields = {
        "transitive_source_files": "list of transitive source files of a target",
    },
)

#add 'resources' ? if so _accumulate_transitive_config_files needs to check for dep in deps if ConfigFiles in dep
SourceAttr = ["tars", "deps", "runtime_deps", "exports"]

def _accumulate_transitive_source_files(accumulated, deps):
    return depset(
        transitive = [dep[SourceFiles].transitive_source_files for dep in deps] + [accumulated],
    )

def _collect_current_source_files(srcs):
    return [file for src in srcs for file in src.files.to_list()]

def _collect_source_files_aspect_impl(target, ctx):
    current_source_files = []
    if hasattr(ctx.rule.attr, "srcs"):
        current_source_files = _collect_current_source_files(ctx.rule.attr.srcs)
    if hasattr(ctx.rule.attr, "resources"):
        current_source_files = current_source_files + _collect_current_source_files(ctx.rule.attr.resources)

    accumulated_source_files = depset(current_source_files)
    for attr in SourceAttr:
        if hasattr(ctx.rule.attr, attr):
            accumulated_source_files = _accumulate_transitive_source_files(accumulated_source_files, getattr(ctx.rule.attr, attr))

    return [SourceFiles(transitive_source_files = accumulated_source_files)]

collect_source_files_aspect = aspect(
    implementation = _collect_source_files_aspect_impl,
    attr_aspects = SourceAttr,
)
```

`sources.bzl`

```py
load("//sources/src/main:sources_aspect.bzl", "SourceFiles", "collect_source_files_aspect")

def _owner_to_bazel_file(fileLabel):
    workspace = fileLabel.workspace_root
    package = fileLabel.package
    if 0 < len(workspace):
        workspace = workspace + "/"
    if 0 < len(package):
        package = package + "/"
    return workspace + package + "BUILD.bazel"

def _collect_source_files_rule_impl(ctx):
    metadata = [ctx.attr.group_id, ctx.attr.artifact_id]
    paths = sorted([f.path for f in ctx.attr.main_artifact_name[SourceFiles].transitive_source_files.to_list()])
    owners = sorted(depset([_owner_to_bazel_file(f.owner) for f in ctx.attr.main_artifact_name[SourceFiles].transitive_source_files.to_list()] + [_owner_to_bazel_file(ctx.label)]).to_list())

    ctx.actions.write(ctx.outputs.sources, "\n".join(metadata + paths + owners))
    ctx.actions.write(ctx.outputs.source_files, "{\"groupId\": \"%s\", \"artifactId\": \"%s\", \"sources\": %s, \"buildFiles\": %s}" % (ctx.attr.group_id, ctx.attr.artifact_id, paths, owners))
    return DefaultInfo(
        runfiles = ctx.runfiles(files = [ctx.outputs.sources, ctx.outputs.source_files]),
    )

source_files = rule(
    implementation = _collect_source_files_rule_impl,
    attrs = {
        "main_artifact_name": attr.label(aspects = [collect_source_files_aspect]),
        "group_id": attr.string(mandatory = True),
        "artifact_id": attr.string(mandatory = True),
    },
    outputs = {"sources": "%{name}.sources.txt", "source_files": "%{name}.sources.json"},
)
```